# Is there a program to create commands for git?

Tags: git

Git have a lot o command and is easy to forget some. So, there is a program that help to create command line for git? This is not a GUI, is to help to create advanced commands.

Comment: Are you asking if you can write shell scripts to automate common tasks? Yes, you can.

Comment: I think he's asking for a program that can be used, by the user, to select the various Git subcommands. Is that correct?

Comment: @Kitsune, yes you are correct. How can I remember all subcommands? I will have to read the man page a lot of time...

Comment: How do you remember the name 'git'?  I often find myself staring at the keyboard trying to remember commands.  Every time I want to edit a file, I have to google 'editor' to remember 'vi', but sometimes I forget 'google' and before I know it the whole day is wasted.  And then I have to find my car keys...

Comment: @Rodrigo You can use Bash completion for Git subcommands. I don't believe there's any included with Git itself, but various thirdparties have created the necessary support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course! See [man git-config](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-config.html). Example: `git config alias.marco '!sh -c "echo polo"'` causes `git marco` to print `polo` (thus playing a children's game familiar in the United States).

Answer (score 0):

`git help` will output a list of commands, and further you can use `git help`*`command`* for help and examples for a specific command, for example `git help status`.